# How to grep lines that start with double forward slash in Linux command line?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

How do I grep lines in a file that start with double forward slash from the Linux command line? The double forward slashes may have spaces before it, but only spaces before it and no other types of characters.

e.g.

```
shell_prompt: ls
shell_prompt: grep .....? file_name
```

Sorry was being unobservant, I didn't notice something that existed before the // characters other than the space. Problem solved. Will award to the guy that answered first.

Comment: You should actually award the guy whose solution was best...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
grep -E '^ *//'
```

Comment: \s would be better, but the OP mentions just spaces

Answer (score 2):

```
grep "//" jquery.js
```

will find all lines that contain `//`. Which if your looking for comments, what you might be interested in.

```
grep "^//" jquery.js
```

will find just lines that start with `//`.

It might me worth your while to start looking into [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: read all the requirements:

```
grep "^ *\\/\\/" file
```

You need two backslashes for escape characters in the shell because you are passing the backslash character to the grep command.

i.e. grep sees the regex string `\/\/`